# Can I manage current & past editions of an annual event with a single WordPress install?

Tags: custom-post-types, configuration

I want to use **a single WP install** to build a site that will present curent and pasts editions of an annual event.

From one year to the next the list of participants and the daily program change entirely. The data from both compose the archive. Other annual variables, like sponsors, don't need to be retained.

The configuration I settled upon is to create a **participant custom post type** and a **program custom post type** for each year: *participants2019* and *program2019*, *participants2020* and *program2020*, *participants2021* and *program2021*, etc.

This allows me to add single posts and archive pages for the CPT for the current year and present past edition summaries on as single pages with custom templates. It makes it easy for the client to find where to edit the info in the Admin. The URLs are good and Polylang is happy with it. The client picks the "current" year via an options page.

So far this works pretty well and the goal of a small hosting footprint is achieved but is not quite optimal. For one it requires that I create the CPTs for future years in advance (I can't expect the client to know how to use the CPT UI plugin). I created an arbitrary 7 editions (2019 to 2025). It also adds a lot of items to the admin menu, which I solved (grouping and hiding) more or less with a plugin.

My question is twofold:
 - is there a better configuration for this?
 - if not, how can I let my client duplicate the current year's CPTs in order to create the CPTs for future edition in a dead simple way?

Comment: Instead of a new CPT all the time, you could create a single "participant" CPT and a single "program" CPT. Then, create a taxonomy called "year" that is applicable to both CPTs. That way, the client can easily add a new taxonomy term each year (it's just like adding a new Category - they'd just do it under Year instead of Category) and just apply that taxonomy to each CPT.

Comment: if I remember right I considered that but decided against it because it is less easy for my client to find and edit/add the participants or program information. They would see Participants in the Admin menu and then have to filter by year, which is a little complicated and repetitive. Right now they see a Participants menu item with Participants 2019, Participants2020, etc. as submenus which is pretty easy.